# glusterfs geo replication on non standard ssh port

Tags: linux, storage, glusterfs

I need to achieve glusterfs geo replication.

In my production environment the port 22 is not open between the servers I want to do replication (This is by design and we have to leave with it).

Is there a way I can use a customize ssh port (i.e 22222) to achieve it.

Is there any other solution for this.

NOTE: I can not use other servers other then this two.

Comment: No-one to answer this question?

Comment: What is stopping you from using port 22222? Is there a firewall in the way? I suppose you must be on a newer setup that is using Firewalld. If so, you probably need to poke holes between the two machines with `firewall-cmd`. You can test connectivity between the two machines with `netcat` (though RHEL’s version is not ideal) or even `telnet`.

Answer (score 9):

Gluster [uses the installed ssh client](https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/blob/91e1d0dd620941c91794d697a8388cd524d2e3bf/xlators/mgmt/glusterd/src/glusterd-geo-rep.c#L5333) meaning you can override configuration using the normal ssh_config.

So create .ssh/config in the homedir of the user that runs glusterfs (probably root) and configure the client using the documented `Host`:

```
[glusterfsnode-hostname]
Port 2222
```

Alternatively, you can [configure glusterfs](https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/blob/58a687a8e0967393428bc5f93f0d32bbc3792f88/doc/admin-guide/en-US/markdown/admin_geo-replication.md#configurable-options) to use a different ssh-command, and add `-p 2222` there